# Lollipop notification icon too small

Tags: android, notifications, icons, android-5.0-lollipop

I'm trying this code,

```
NotificationCompat.Builder nfBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            context)
            ..setContentTitle(
                    "XYZ")
            .setContentText("ABC")
            .setContentIntent(pIntent)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
            .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.woj_ic_launcher);

    Notification notification = nfBuilder.build();

    NotificationManager nfManager = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    nfManager.notify(requestCode, notification);
```

Problem is, it works fine with all other platforms but with lollipop, it shows very small icon with grey circle around it. I tried changing icon sizes and using setLargeIcon() method but still no joy.

[image]

Comment: Could I see your image and its dimensions

Comment: did you ever solve this? I am having the same issue

Comment: Not yet. For now i keep it as it is.

Comment: having the same problem

Comment: I've been trying to solve this for two days now. Still no luck.

Comment: Use this to generate notifications icons: https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/

Comment: More than one year, can you please post solution. It would be great. I am too facing this issue.

Comment: i'm having the same issue. in notification bar icon shows fine, when pulled down to see full notification the icon is seen as @Sushant describes: small, centered, and grey background. Tryed [link](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-notification.html), but does not help. Tryed different icon sizes but does not help either. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 4):

The image should have square proportion.
Use this tool (https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-notification.html) and then make sure you use the "Api v11" icons, since they have the square proportion you need, the older version had a little more height.

Recap:
I got to tell I don't really see you icon being too small, in fact that's the greatest icon size I could get, look..

[image: The size is the same as yours]

And for the "grey" background issue, is something like [Notification.Builder.setColor(Color.RED)](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setColor(int)) not working for you?

Comment: actually it is square proportion and transparent background. I'll check tool you suggested. would be appreciated if u provide link to this tool.

Comment: @Sushant My bad, just edited the answer, hope it helps.

Comment: i'll look into that. apart from the question, this bubble background looks awesome. can you share how did you do this ?

Comment: Jaja, that's my phone wallpaper what you see through the notification transparency. Is a photo of my windshield on a rainy day.

Comment: @Sushant Could you tell me if it is fixed? (and mark as the correct answer ;) )

Comment: The 'setColor' tip helped me out. Now it is small but not grey... Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is how it sorted out finally:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder nBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext());
nBuilder.setContentTitle("notificationTitle");
nBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher1);
nBuilder.setLargeIcon(bitmap);
nBuilder.setContentText(notificationText);

NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.notify(notificationId, nBuilder.build());
```

1. Get a drawable/mipmap.
2. Convert it to bitmap.
3. Set the bitmap using `setLargeIcon(Bitmap bitmap)` method of `NotificationCompat.Builder`.

**Note:**`setSmallIcon()` is a mendatory method here. You can't skip it.